# Change the parameters from a method

Tags: java, multithreading, parameters

i am new into programming in java and i hope i have chose the right title.
First my Code:

```
public class main 
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        SysOutSleep sos = new SysOutSleep("Test", 450, 3 );//set the value

        Thread t = new Thread(sos); 

        t.start(); 

        //here i want to change the parameters from sos 
        //they should be something like that ("Test2", 390, 1)

        //and after that i start the thread again with the new parameters

        t.start();
    }

}
```

So how can i change them, thank you in advance :)

Comment: What is `SysOutSleep`? (Also, I think you mean you want to change the *arguments*. *Parameters* are the types a method accepts, *arguments* are the values we pass to them.)

Comment: Not 100% sure what you want, question is very vague! You change the parameters by using variables (thats in general the way you should do it).

Comment: You can't `start` a thread twice. Is this a Java program?

Answer (score 3):

You can't start the same Thread isntance twice, which means you'll have to create a new Thread :

```
SysOutSleep sos = new SysOutSleep("Test", 450, 3);
Thread t = new Thread(sos); 
t.start(); 

sos = new SysOutSleep("Test2", 390, 1);
t = new Thread(sos);
t.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to use another parameters in the same method then you just need to change the values in

```
SysOutSleep sos = new SysOutSleep("Test", 450, 3 );//set the value
```

to

```
SysOutSleep sos = new SysOutSleep("Test2", 390, 1 );
```

And if you want both  method to be executed with both the cases and using two different threads then you will have to create two threads.

```
SysOutSleep sos1 = new SysOutSleep("Test", 450, 3); // create object of SysOutSleep class and invoke constructor of SysOutSleep class with the given parameters
Thread t1 = new Thread(sos); // create thread for sos1 object and starts thread
t1.start();  // after start thread it will run the run method of thread

sos2 = new SysOutSleep("Test2", 390, 1);
Thread t2 = new Thread(sos);
t2.start();
```

Comment: What's `t2`? Java is strongly typed.

Comment: Alright. While your answer is not wrong in the true sense, it has some flaws. 1) The code is badly formatted. 2) You don't explain why you created a second thread?. 3) What do you really mean by `If you just want to use another parameters in the same method then you just need to change the values in`?..Just some tips on getting returns on your investment of time. As the answer stands currently, I don't see any chance of it being upvoted.

Comment: @kirti You really should learn how to format your code better. It is unreadable otherwise and you potentially miss being upvoted. So this time I improved the formatting for you.